# Nuxtjs/apollo is there a way to make apollo wait on other requests before starting the query?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

i need to make one of two queries based on the result of another request to a third party, is there a way to tell Apollo to wait for that request to finish and return the appropriate query for Apollo ? or should i just make the request and add the appropriate query manually to Apollo when i get the results ?

Comment: query has skip option, blocking flag

Comment: @xadm so i can skip the the query, fire tha other request when mounting and start that query ?

Comment: you can chain many queries, next fired by data from previous one

Comment: @xadm yes but the request  that the queries are waiting for is a third party REST request not a query

Comment: skip is just boolean option, you can connect it with ...anything

Comment: @xadm could you provide an example for a case like mine plz ?

Comment: `const [blockIt, setBlockIt] = useState(true); ... useQuery(MY_QUERY,  {skip: blockIt}) ... some axios/fetch ... resolve {. setBlockIt(false);}` ... query is not run until data fetched and `blockIt` state/flag not changed/cleared

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @xadm i was able to get this to work, i am gonna post the vuejs code i reached to do this same effect.

First in my data i should have a variable to skips the query so it won't execute on load...

```
...
data () {
  return {
    blockQuery: true
  }
}
```

and then when i am defining my query i should pass that `blockQuery` to stop it from executing

```
apollo: {
  myDataQuery: {
    query: <the gql query>
    skip () {
      return this.blockQuery // this is true so the query wont execute on load
    }
  }
}
```

then i should make whatever third party request i need, for example...

```
async mounted () {
  const response = await <my request that resolves>
  // after i made my request i should change the blockQuery to false so it would start the query
  this.blockQuery = false // after this changes to false it will start the query.
}
```